# Decoding an unknown CRC or checksum?

Tags: crc

I've been trying decode the CRC or checksum algorithm that is being used for the serial communication between a drone and its camera for about a week without a lot of luck and I was wondering if anybody here sees something I am missing or has any suggestions.

A typical packet looks like this:

```
FE1A390100020001AE0BE0FF090046250B00040000004E0D32080008540D8808F4016B54
```

They always start with 0xFE. The 2nd byte is the total size of the packet minus 10 bytes. The packet sizes vary, but I think I am specifically interested the 0x1A size. Byte 3 seems to be a packet counter because it usually increases by 1, but sometimes I have seen it jump to a completely different number for a few packets (usually when changing to a 0x22 size packet) before resuming the increment by 1 sequence. The last 2 bytes always change and I believe are the checksum or CRC. All the rest of the bytes seem to stay the same from one 0x1A packet to the next unless I manipulate the drones radio controls.

Right after powering up there is a series of packets that I assume is for initializing the communication. They are the shortest packets and have the least amount of change between them so it seems like they might be the easyiest to look at. Here are the first 7 bytes sent after powering it on.

```
From Drone to camera
Time:
8.3982205   FE030001000000010200018F68
8.39934725  FE03010100000001020001A844
8.400473958 FE03020100000001020001C130
8.401600708 FE050301000000000000000001AAE8
8.402900792 FE1A040100020001000000000000000000000C000300000853060008AB028808F4014629
8.406020958 FE22050100030002000000000000000000000000000000000000B3FFFFFFDE22006300FF615110050000C956
8.4098345   FE1A060100020001000000000000000000000C000300000853060008AB028808F40180A9
```

If I put the first 3 packets into reveng with -w 16 -s then it comes back with:

```
reveng: warning: you have only given 3 samples
reveng: warning: to reduce false positives, give 4 or more samples
width=16  poly=0x1487  init=0x0334  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0000  check=0xa5b9  residue=0x0000  name=(none)
```

If i add the 4th packet it finds the same poly, but there rest of it looks differnt:

```
width=16  poly=0x1487  init=0x417d  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x5582  check=0xbfa2  residue=0xb059  name=(none)
```

If i add the 5th packet reveng comes back with no model found.

However, if I remove packet 4 and then run it with packets, 1,2,3 and 5 if finds the same poly again, but different values for the rest:

```
width=16  poly=0x1487  init=0x804b  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x0138  check=0x7dcc  residue=0xc8ca  name=(none)
```

Most combinations of packets containing a 0x1A size packet and the first 3 initialization packets that I run through reveng come back with 'no model found'. So far every time I have run reveng with only 0x1a sized packets has failed to find a model.

I think it is possible that after the initialization packets it some how incorporates info it receives from the camera to the drone into the CRC calculation for the data going from the drone to the camera, but there isn't a lot of data in those packets. Here are the first 9 packets that are sent from the camera to the drone. Prior to the first 0x1A packet being sent from the drone, the only data sent from the camera seems to be 0x7D0001.

```
From camera to drone:
Time
3.474456792 FE0500020000000000007D00013D40
4.475220208 FE0501020000000000007D000168C5
5.476483875 FE0502020000000000007D00018642
6.477295958 FE0503020000000000007D0001D3C7
7.4783405   FE0504020000000000007D00014B45
8.479420458 FE06050200010003FA078538B838B3
8.480811667 FE0506020000000000007D0001F047
9.48057875  FE0507020000000000007D0001A5C2
9.481883    FE06080200010003F9078638B8386037
```

I have tried incorporating 0x7D0001 into the packets and running them through reveng, but that didn't seem to help.

I have also tried reveng -w 8 -s on various combinations of packets without finding a model. And I have tried various checksum algos manually (possibly incorrectly) without success.

I have a bunch more data that I have captured here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v8MCaXOvP_2Wv_hcaqhUZnXvqNI1_2Ur

Any ideas? Suggestions? This has been driving me nuts for a week

Comment: Have you tried reverse engineering the code on the drone or the camera to see how it generates/decodes the crc?

Comment: No I haven't. I believe that the FW on the drone is protected, I assume it is on the camera also. Even if it wasn't or if I tried to use the firmware that is available for download, i really dont know where to begin with decompiling that code. So far as I know the source code isn't available anywhere.

Comment: I think might have just needed to complain about it on a forum before making any progress. I haven't cracked it yet, but I did find that the structure of the packet is fairly similar to the Mavlink version 1 protocol. From https://mavlink.io/en/guide/serialization.html

Comment: It has the same basic structure except the total header is only 6 bytes vs 10 bytes in the data I collected.   It says that it uses CRC-16 X.25 calculated from the whole packet except for the first FE byte, but also includes a CRC_Extra byte. The CRC_Extra byte is calculated by taking the CRC of the string of message id name. The header should have the message ID, so if they used the standard naming then I can calculate the CRC. Then I need to figure out how it gets merged with the CRC bytes (do I just add it has extra data?). But it is at least a possible explanation of what I'm looking at.